# ICO Token sale payment process

Tags: transactions, ico, crowdsale, presale, payments

How can one start selling their coins on their custom website for ETH and Bitcoin?

I was checking bunnytoken.com, they have very simple payment process script, which includes referral solution.

Each time user register, they get unique ETH or bitcoin address, to sent the money.

I been looking for similar script, but cant find any. Can anyone help, if they already know which site I can use or script?

Answer (score 1):

They mostly proceed that off contract, with payment processor and manually or with a bot task sending the token back when the payment is confirmed.

Check that, it's the best post in my opinion about this question.

[ICO crypto-currencies accepted during the sale: ETH, BTC, or even fiat?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/26308/19037)